# Imprimir tablero 4 en raya C++

Tags: c++

tengo que realizar un juego de 4 en raya con una estética definida, y estoy realizando el código pero no sé por qué no me queda con la estética marcada. Llevo un rato largo con esto, si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería. La estetica que me definen es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi código es este:

```
{
    char linea;
    int i, j;
    for (i=65; i<TAMY+65; i++)
    {
        linea = i;
        cout << "  " << linea << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (i=0; i< TAMX; i++)
    { 
        cout << "|";
        cout << "---" << endl;
        cout << "|   ";
        for (j=0; j<TAMY; j++)
        {    
            cout << "|";
            cout << "---";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Y a mi me compila así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Por cada iteración de `i` hay dos `endl`. De hecho, no queda muy claro porqué imprimes nada (aparte del `endl`, claro) fuera del bucle más interno.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se trata de imprimir cosas gráficas en la terminal, lo mejor es hacer una matriz del tamaño de lo que quieres imprimir, luego la rellenas y al final la imprimes. Esto te va a permitir manipular lo que se va a imprimir de mejor forma.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int tamX=29, tamY=30; //Definimos el tamaño de lo que vamos a imprimir
    char porImprimir[tamY][tamX]; //Creamos una matriz de caracteres

    //Tenemos que inicializar la matriz
    for(int i=0; i<tamY; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<tamX; j++){
            porImprimir[i][j] = ' '; //En este caso usaré espacio
        }
    }

    //Solo en el primer renglón ponemos letras
    char letra = 'A';
    for(int i=2; i<tamX; i+=4){
        porImprimir[0][i] = letra++; //Y la incrementamos encada ocasión
        //Ojo, deberás validar esto si te pasas de la Z
    }

    //Aqui llenaremos las lineas verticales y horizontales
    for(int i=0; i<tamY; i++){
        //Con exepción de la primer linea, todas las impares llevan renglón
        if(i > 0 && i%2==1){ 
            for(int j=0; j<tamX; j++){
                porImprimir[i][j] = '-';
            }
        }

        //Para dibujar las columnas pondremos la barrica cada 4 espacios
        for(int j=0; j<tamX; j+=4){
            porImprimir[i][j] = '|';
        }
    }

    //Al final imprimimos todo lo que rellenamos
    for(int i=0; i<tamY; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<tamX; j++){
            //Imprimimos juntos todos los que van en un renglón
            cout << porImprimir[i][j]; 
        }
        cout << endl; //Y un salto de linea cuando acabamos ese renglón
    }
}
```

Todo eso te va a generar una salida como la que te han pedido.

[image: Salida del código]

Espero haberte ayudado! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
char c = 'A';
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++){
    cout<<" ";
    for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
        if(j == 1){
          cout<<c;
          c++;
        }else{
            cout<<" ";
        }
    }
}

cout<<endl;
for(int i = 1; i<=12; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<7; j++){
        cout<<"|";
        if(i%2==0 && i>1 && j<6 ){
            for(int jj = 0; jj<3; jj++){
                cout<<"-";
            }
        }else{
            for(int jj = 0; jj<3; jj++){
                cout<<" ";
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

    
return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).